# SwiftUI - Clicking on the add attachment icon in chat crashes with libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload

Tags: getstream-io, getstream-chat

I'm new to gettream chats and I'm trying to flesh out our chat stream  I'm following the tutorial for SwiftUI.  Everything went without a hitch.  I'm simply using the built in UI using the ChatChannelListView().  Everything works fine until you try to add a file attachment (the paperclip icon).   Then, it crashes with:

SwiftUI - Clicking on the add attachment icon in chat crashes with: `libsystem_kernel.dylib__abort_with_payload`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
import SwiftUI
import StreamChat
import StreamChatSwiftUI

struct MessagesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ChatChannelListView()
    }
}

struct MessagesView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MessagesView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you specify the "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description" in your Info.plist? This is needed to display the photo library.

Additionally, you will need the following two for the camera functionality:
"Privacy - Microphone Usage Description"
"Privacy - Camera Usage Description"

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am checking the state of our tutorials and I notice this one is missing the usage description info.

https://getstream.io/tutorials/swiftui-chat/